# My SQL Join is only producting half the right aggregate output

Tags: sql, join

```
SELECT E.DNO as DeptNum, COUNT(E.SSN) as EmployeeCount, COUNT(D.ESSN) as DependentCount
FROM Dependent D
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Employee E ON D.ESSN = E.SSN
GROUP BY E.DNO
```

The goal is to find the total number of employees and total number of dependents for every department. I am utilizing an Employee Table that features Employee, SSN, Department Number and a Dependent Table that has Dependent SSN, Birthdate, and Gender.

The output should be as follows

```
Dept Num            Employee Count        DependentCount
1                          1                    0
2                          3                    7
3                          5                    2
```

But, instead I am getting

```
Dept Num            Employee Count        DependentCount
1                          1                    0
2                          9                    7
3                          4                    2
```

One thing of note is the dependent's SSN is equivalent to the parent's SSN - that is the only way to define the relationship between the tables. Also, I know I need an outer join because we want to list ALL departments, despite the fact there are 0 mentions of it for Dept 1 in Dependent Table.

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `distinct` so things don't get double counted:

```
SELECT E.DNO as DeptNum, COUNT(DISTINCT E.SSN) as EmployeeCount, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT D.ESSN) as DependentCount
FROM Employee E LEFT JOIN
     Dependent D
     ON D.ESSN = E.SSN
GROUP BY E.DNO
```

Comment: So, here's a weird question. I just did COUNT(DISTINCT E.SSN) for Employee and that solved the problem. BUT, when I do COUNT(Distinct D.SSN) for dependent, it made it not work. So, I have a count distinct for employee and count as it was in my original post for dependents and it works. I'm assuming that's because some children have the same SSN which links back to the parent. But, it feels like weird formatting to have distinct employee but not distinct dependent

Comment: @buckywucky: do you still have department 'Dept 1' ?

Comment: Dept 1 needs to be included. It asks for total employee and dependent count in each department

Comment: Yeas, that's in your question, but if you run the query that Gordon gave, does it return 'Dept 1' ?

Comment: @buckywucky . . . Two parents could be working at the company with the same dependent.